# Print Invoice/order details in woocommerce from woocommerce admin order page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to print the order details of my Woocommerce order's through a button that displays in admin order page, something like this [woocommerce admin order page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXpPt.png) when you click that button a print window opens, something like this [Print window screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbbMy.png) so I can print my order invoice. The problem I'm facing is the print window only opens for the very first order that's on top of the line and for the other order's when you click the button it just refreshes the page, I wanna fix this & I need your guys input on this.

I'm using this code

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'my_custom_order_column' );
function my_custom_order_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['my_custom_column'] = 'Print Invoice';
    return $columns;
}
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'my_custom_order_column_data' );
function my_custom_order_column_data( $column ) {
    if ( 'my_custom_column' === $column ) {
echo '<button id="myButton">Get Order Details</button>';
    }
$order_id = get_the_ID();
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$order_note = $order->get_customer_note();
$order_no = $order->get_order_number();
$order_total = $order->get_total();
$total_tax = $order->get_total_tax();
$subtotal = $order->get_subtotal();
$items=$order->get_items();

$billing_email=$order->get_billing_email();
$billing_phone=$order->get_billing_phone();

//$shipping_email = $order->get_shipping_email();
//$shipping_phone=$order->get_shipping_phone();

   $shipping_address_1 =$order->get_shipping_address_1();
$shipping_address_2 =$order->get_shipping_address_2();
$shipping_city = $order->get_shipping_city();
$shipping_state = $order->get_shipping_state();
$shipping_country = $order->get_shipping_country();
$shipping_postcode = $order->get_shipping_postcode();

   $billing_address_1 =$order->get_billing_address_1();
$billing_address_2 =$order->get_billing_address_2();
$billing_city = $order->get_billing_city();
$billing_state = $order->get_billing_state();
$billing_country = $order->get_billing_country();
$billing_postcode = $order->get_billing_postcode();

//echo '<div id="orderDetails"></div>';
  ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("#myButton").click(function(){
  myWindow=window.open(' ',' ', 'width=500, height=500');
  myWindow.document.write('<?php echo'<style>body{ background-color: #fff; margin: 0;  padding: 0;} </style>';
echo'<style> h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{ margin: 0; padding: 0;} p{ margin: 0; padding: 0; } </style>';
echo'<style> .container{ width: 100%; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; } .brand-section{ background-color: #b2ac88; padding: 10px 40px;} </style>'; echo'<style>.logo{ width: 50%;} .row{ display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; } .col-6{ width: 50%; flex: 0 0 auto; } .text-white{ color: #fff; } </style>';
echo'<style> .company-details{ float: right; text-align: right;} .body-section{ padding: 16px; border: 1px solid gray;} </style>';
echo'<style>.heading{ font-size: 20px; margin-bottom: 08px; } .sub-heading{ color: #262626; margin-bottom: 05px; } </style>';
echo'<style> table{ background-color: #fff; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; } </style>';
echo'<style> table thead tr{ border: 1px solid #111; background-color: #fff; } table td { vertical-align: middle !important; text-align: center; }</style>';
echo'<style> table th, table td { padding-top: 08px; padding-bottom: 08px; } .table-bordered{box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0.5px gray;} </style>';
echo'<style> table-bordered td, .table-bordered th { order: 1px solid #dee2e6; } .text-right{ ext-align: end;} .w-20{ width: 20%;} </style>';
echo'<style>.float-right{float: right; }</style>';
echo'<h3>Inovice</h3>';
echo'<div class="container">';
echo '<div class="brand-section">';
echo '<div class="row">';
echo '<div class="col-6">';
                    echo '<h1 class="text-white">Order No.</h1>'.$order_no.'</div>';
echo '<div class="col-6">';
                    echo '<div class="company-details">';
echo '<h2 class="text-white">Oven Fresh</h2>';
                       echo '<p class="text-white">Unit No. 210 2nd floor,Mahim Industrial Estate,Off Cadel Road Mahim,Mumbai-400016 <br>GST No: 27AAUCA4280D1ZI <br> FSSAI NO:11521004000462 <br>State Name: Maharashtra, Code: 27</p>';
                       echo '<p class="text-white">+91-8080-146666</p>';
                    echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="body-section">';
           echo '<div class="row">';
                echo '<div class="col-6">';
                   echo '<h2 class="heading">Billing Address</h2>';  echo'<br>'.$billing_address_1.$billing_address_2.$billing_city.$billing_state.$billing_country.$billing_postcode ;
                   echo '<p class="sub-heading">Email </p>'.$billing_email;
                   echo '<p class="sub-heading">Phone </p>'.$billing_phone;
                   
              echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="col-6">';
                   echo '<h2 class="heading">Shipping Address</h2>'.$shipping_address_1.$shipping_address_2.$shipping_city.$shipping_state.$shipping_country.$shipping_postcode;
//  echo '<p class="sub-heading">Delivery Date </p>'.$delivery_date;
                 //  echo '<p class="sub-heading">Time Slot</p>'.$time_slot;
   foreach ( $order->get_meta_data() as $meta ) {
if ( $meta->key === 'Delivery Date' || $meta->key === 'Time Slot' ) {
            echo '<p><strong>' . $meta->key . ':</strong> ' . $meta->value . '</p>';
        }
}
  echo '<p><strong>Customer Note :</strong>'.$order_note.'</p>';
              echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="body-section">';
           echo '<h3 class="heading">Ordered Items</h3>';
            echo '<br>';
            echo '<table class="table-bordered">';
                echo '<thead>';
                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<th>Product Name</th>';
                        echo '<th>Quantity</th>';
                        echo '<th>HSN Code</th>';
                        echo '<th>Price</th>';
echo '<th class="w-20">Grandtotal</th>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                echo '</thead>';
                echo '<tbody>';
         foreach ( $items as $item ) {
 $product=$item->get_product();
$product_name = $item->get_name();
$quantity= $item->get_quantity();
$price = $item->get_product()->get_regular_price();
     $hsn_code=$product->get_meta('_hsn_code');
  $grandtotal = wc_price($price * $quantity);
 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td>'.$product_name.'</td>';
 echo '<td>'.$quantity.'</td>';
 echo '<td>'.$hsn_code.'</td>';
 echo '<td>'.$price.'</td>';
 echo '<td>'.$grandtotal.'</td>';
 echo '</tr>';
  }

echo'<tr>';
                       echo '<td colspan="4" class="text-right">Sub Total</td>';
                       echo '<td>'.$subtotal.'</td>';
                   echo '</tr>';
                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td colspan="4" class="text-right">Tax</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$total_tax.'</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo'<td colspan="4" class="text-right">Total</td>';
                        echo'<td>'.$order_total.'</td>';
                    echo'</tr>';
echo'</tbody>';
            echo '</table>';
echo '<div>';
            echo '<p>Footer </p>';
        echo '</div>';      
echo '</div>'; ?>');
  setTimeout(function () {
myWindow.document.close();
myWindow.focus();
myWindow.print();
myWindow.close();
}, 1000)
});
        });
</script>
<?php
}
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: You are missing that IDs in HTML need to be unique.

Comment: Ohh, Thank you!! I've solved this issue now.